# What is the name of that audio cable that goes from motherboard to case?

Tags: audio, motherboard, case

I realized that the audio jack connectors in front of my case don't work.

After opening the case, it's obvious, there is no cable connected.

[image]

[image]

The motherboard is a Gigabyte Z87P-D3 and the case a Fractal Design R2.

I'd like to buy that cable but I couldn't figure out its name.

What is the name of that cable?

Comment: The best description is a “HD Audio” cable. This isn’t to be confused by HDMI or an optical audio cable. But your description  of the case isn’t detailed enough Fractal Design R2 doesn’t exist anywhere on the Fractal Design website

Comment: The closest case I could find says it came with an HD Audio cable, I have no idea, what the first screenshot is of exactly. I was able to find a suitable duplicate.

Comment: Check with cabinet vendor if they have correct spare. In case you do not find a suitable cable, consider alternatives like installing a separate Front Audio Panel something like https://www.amazon.com/C-Zone-Floppy-Earphone-Interface-Adapter/dp/B01KV029F2/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2LRQQGCIVVMUF&keywords=front+panel+audio+connector&qid=1684810132&sprefix=front+audio%2Caps%2C1195&sr=8-1 that comes with wiring intact and correct HD Audio connector that goes into F-Audio pins on motherboard

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm going to do, went hunting for it today, absolutely nothing in many stores.